# How to convert JSON serialized data to NSDictionary in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I Have Used the following method to convert data to dictionary in my App but it shows json object was nil.

It's printing "jsonObject is null".
Is there any problem with "error:nil".

```
- (void)postNonceToServer:(NSString *)paymentMethodNonce {
// Update URL with your server


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];



NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"payment_method_nonce":paymentMethodNonce,@"amount":amountStr,@"tripid":tripIdStr,@"currencycode":currencyStr};

[manager POST:@"http:url.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //NSArray *response = responseObject;
    //response = responseObject;

    NSLog(@"responseObject is %@",responseObject);

    jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                error:nil];
    NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@",jsonObject);


    }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];

}
```

Comment: No, there is "no issue" with `error:nil`, it's allowed, but it can clearly help to debug your issue, and avoiding using errors parameters is not recommended. It's like hiding warnings in your car. As long as it works, it's okay. But when it doesn't... Also, if you show `responseObject` (converted before into NSString), we could help.

Comment: This can happen if the responseObject is `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. `JSONObjectWithData` requires `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. That's what was happening to me on WatchOS2.2

Comment: Can you say detail please@Larme

Comment: Can you say detail please@Brandon

Comment: jsonObject was return always null.

Comment: If `jsonObject` is `nil`, the error is not. Don't ignore it, catch it!

Comment: Pass in a value for the error parameter and then log the error so you can determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: If you show your full code I will help you brother

Comment: I edit and post the full method@user3182143

Comment: Could you show us the value of `responseObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am using AFNetworking 3.0. So i will give you "POST" method code in AFNetworking 3.0 version.

Step 1 :- Create one NSObject Class and write down this method in .h file.

```
+ (void)requestPostUrl: (NSString *)serviceName parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

Step 2 :- Write down this code in .m file
here "kBaseURL" means Web service URL and "serviceName" name of service.

```
+ (void)requestPostUrl: (NSString *)serviceName parameters:(NSDictionary *)dictParams success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responce))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager.requestSerializer setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock:^NSString * _Nonnull(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, id  _Nonnull parameters, NSError * _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable error) {

    //Here your data converting in JSON.
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:error];
    NSString *argString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return argString;
}];

NSString *strService = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kBaseURL,serviceName];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];
//[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please wait..."];
[SVProgressHUD show];
[manager POST:strService parameters:dictParams progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {


    if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

        if(success) {
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            success(responseObject);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        if(success) {
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            NSLog(@"POST Response  : %@",response);
            success(response);
        }
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    if(failure) {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        failure(error);
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: Ok, fine... send me your error or error-snap short, i will figure out. @Saravanakumar